# Outlook Add In - detecting newly entered recipient email addresses

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I noticed that when I first type in a new email address in the "To" field, it is not underlined. If I also invoke our add in at that time, the MailItem.Recipients collection is empty. However, if I wait a few seconds, the email address will become underlined, and it will also be added to the Recipients collection.
Is there a way to force the evaluation of the address immediately or through code?

Answer (score 1):

Try Recipients.ResolveAll.  If automatic name checking is enabled in Outlook Options it should try to resolve the address as soon as you type it.  Also note that MailItem.PropertyChange will fire when an address is added, but it will fire for the To, Cc and Bcc properties at the same time even if no data is entered into all of those fields.

Comment: Eric, Thank you for the response. I have automatic name checking enabled. I also tried Recipients.ResolveAll. However, the Recipients collection is still empty until the address is underlines. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing that at all - Recipients.Count = 1 for an unresolved address for me. What if you tried MailItem.Save first?